# Models structure for relationship between field types, page types and pages in ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am fairly new to .NET Core and C# in general, I can create a simple ASP.NET Core MVC application with simple models and I would like to further my understand of modeling in general.

I have worked with CMS's before and is common to have a "Page Type" that you can add "Field Types" and then create pages based on the page type, unfortunately I seem to have problems visualizing how would models be structure to achieve this in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Examples of fields:

- Image
- Select
- Url
- Html

Example of PageType Article:

- Title
- Image
- Html

Example of PageType Blog:

- Title
- Select
- Html

Example of Page #1:

- PageType Article

Example of Page #2:

- PageType Blog

Comment: probably you are looking for partial views, with them you can create templates for yuor article and blog or for dynamic content you can see how blazor works. i daut that somebody will write the code for you. your quesrion is too abstract

Comment: I have to agree it seems abstract and i have trouble explaining it properly. But i am not looking for the code more like a theoretical explanation of how to combine those elements. For example, if i wanted to have a book reservation site i would create a book model a user model and a reservation model with the book and the user having a one to many relationships with the reservation model and the reservation model table holding the book Id and User Id for each reservation Instance. I just can't see how to relate them in this pages case.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the relationship between your requirements, the book model, the user model, and the reservation model? Or what is your business logic like?